# ip6 on a wrt54g Via Charter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, ipv6

I was told you guys might be a better site to ask this question.  Im looking to play around with ipv6 and would like to get my router (wrt54gv3.1) working.  My ISP(charter)  offers a 6rd relay to use.   My router is setup with dd-wrt(standard)  so It does have the ability to set it.  But I'm a bit confused as to where the information needs to go.

According to the dd-wrt website this is a startup example script using comcast information:

```
insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/ipv6/sit.ko
sleep 5 
HOST6RD=$(nslookup 6rd.comcast.net |grep "Address"|awk '{ print $3 }'|grep -v 192.168.1.1 -m1)
WANIP="$(ifconfig vlan2 | sed -n '/inet /{s/.*addr://;s/ .*;p}')"
if [ -n "$WANIP" ]
then 
V6PREFIX=$(printf ' 2001:55c:%02x%02x:%02x%02x' $(echo $WANIP | tr . ' '))
ip tunnel add tun6rd mode sit ttl 255 remote any local $WANIP
ip link set tun6rd mtu 1280
ip link set tun6rd up
ip addr add $V6PREFIX:0::1/32 dev tun6rd
ip addr add $V6PREFIX:1::1/64 dev br0
ip -6 route add 2000::/3 via ::$HOST6RD dev tun6rd
kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/radvd.pid)
fi
echo "interface br0 { \
MinRtrAdvInterval 3; MaxRtrAdvInterval 10; AdvLinkMTU 1280; AdvSendAdvert on; \
prefix $V6PREFIX::/64 { AdvOnLink on; AdvAutonomous on; AdvValidLifetime 86400; \
AdvPreferredLifetime 86400; }; };" \
> /tmp/radvd.conf
radvd -C /tmp/radvd.conf start
```

Charter's info is

```
6rd Prefix = 2602:100::/32
Border Relay Address = 68.114.165.1
6rd prefix length = 32
IPv4 mask length = 0
Primary DNS Address = 2607:f428:1::5353:1 
Secondary DNS Address = 2607:f428:2::5353:1
```

Could someone help out putting the correct information in?

Comment: This DD-WRT forum topic explains someone successfully configuring Charter's 6rd relay:  http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=652852

Comment: Thanks,  I've seen this one before,  but it does not seem to be working.                                                                                                     3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> 
    inet6 fe80::213:10ff:fefe:913a/64 scope link 
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP>